# Изображение dxf файла в окне tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Всем привет, передо мной встала сложная задача,смысл которой заключался в отображении dxf файла как изображение в окне tkinter.Я пытался выполнить эту задачу путем открытия файла как изображение,но ничего хорошего из этого не вышло,искал решение этой задачи на зарубежных ресурсах,но так ничего и не нашел.
Можете подсказать как решить эту задачу или посоветовать какой-нибудь ресурс,который поможет мне?  Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: dxf с точки зрения tkinter не изображение (как и какой-нибудь svg или другой векторный формат). Нужно или найти библиотеку, которая умеет рендерить изображения из этих файлов, потом изображения отображать через tkinter, или брать парсер для dxf, получать описание примитивов (дуг, отрезков, текста), потом эти примитивы рисовать на холсте tkinter (create_line, create_arc, create_text).

Comment: Программа конвертирования из dxf. Нужно будет ее поставить и вызвать из скрипта. В ссылке пример на питоне: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58907848/5909792